# How to map a Deque with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

How can I map a Deque with hibernate?

```
@Entity
class MyClass {
    @OneToMany
    Deque<StackObject> stack = new LinkedList<StackObject>();
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking constructor public org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl(org.slf4j.Logger,java.util.List): Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements
```